# Configure group permissions on OpenVPN Access Server

Tags: openvpn, user-permissions

I have a OpenVPN Access Server working for N users. Everyone has access to different networks like `172.16.10.0/24`, `172.16.11.0/24` and so on.

Now, I'm trying to restrict the access. Only a couple of users will have access to the network `172.16.99.0/24`. So, I created a group called "admin-access" with this configuration.

[image]

**When I try to assign this group to a user, he can't connect to the VPN.**

[image]

These are the logs:

```
2017-08-17 12:56:09 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
2017-08-17 12:56:09 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
2017-08-17 12:56:09 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
2017-08-17 12:56:09 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1502988969,EXITING,auth-failure,,
```

**If I change the group back to "No Default Group", he can connect to the VPN again.**

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the OpenVPN Access Server log, and the problem was there's no a "Group Default IP Address Network" configured. I set it up and it's working.

[image]